Uploading GoPro Files Kills My Internet
I'm a bit confused with this one. When setting an upload off on my GoPro Hero 11, my internet dies. As in, completely dies. My other devices report "Connected but no internet available". My desktop PC is connected and I can happily connect to my router while the upload is in progress but again no internet so it's definitely an internet issue, not WiFi.
Interestingly, the upload fails every time after about an hour. My suspicion is that because the download is dead, it can't talk to the servers and fails.
If I run a speed test on the router (TP Link Archer VR2800) it reports offline.
If I cancel the upload on the GoPro things return to normal.
What can I do? I see no way of throttling the GoPro. I can't (ideally) just live with the lack of internet temporarily because it just fails to upload so I'm stuck unable to upload my footage.
Any thoughts? Can I somehow throttle my devices upload speed to stop it killing the internet? Can't think of anything else here but seems very odd for an upload to totally kill an internet connection.

@JoepvanSteen No it isn't.

Restart your router? Try a different internet connection (hotspot, for instance)? Network devices should not be overcome by a large file upload. It's probably not an internet issue, but a home network device issue, as in, your router, or your modem, are the most likely culprits. If you disconnect every other device and only the upload is running, does that change anything?
